# The result of back propagation for a neural network

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, backpropagation

I have created a neural network that feeds an image into a convolutional neural net, then feeds the flattened output of this network into an artificial neural network.

I have a feeling that my backward propagation is not working properly.

Mind you, I wrote all of it from scratch in vanilla javascript.

The final point of control for me as the programmer is when I input the desired output into the backwards propagation algorithm to calculate the deltas and update the weights. After running backwards propagation I run forward propagation with identical input data to the data that was put into the network before backward propagation to see the change in the output layer based on the new weight values.

For each individual output of my neural network's final layer if it is between the output before backward propagation and the desired output then the network successfully propagated backwards for that output. In my network I had 4 outputs. I took the average of how many outputs were correct for each time back propagation was run and on average I got 0.773206751. About 77% of the time the gradient moved in the correct direction. So 23% of the time the network returned an output in the incorrect direction or returned an output that surpassed the desired output(went too far in the right direction).

In a neural network after running backwards propagation should the output after back propagation be closer to the desired output 100% of the time? What could cause these types of inaccuracies(or are there too many potential causes)?

It is unfortunately a problem that I cannot debug(because there are too many small numbers to keep track of). Unless there is a way to debug this problem, but I'm not sure.

architecture

```
input to CNN[102, 102, 4]
conv: kernel[9*9] stride:3 output:[32, 32, 16] act: ReLU
conv: kernel[5*5] stride:3 output:[10, 10, 32] act: ReLU
max-pool: pool_dim[2*2] stride:2 output:[5, 5, 32]
flatten: from [5, 5, 32] to 800 neurons
inp layer: 800 neurons
hidden layer: [800, 402] act: ReLU
output layer: [402, 4] act: for first 3 in output softmax for the fourth in output linear.
it is an a2c network.
```

Comment: I'm having a bit of a trouble understanding your question. Maybe some context would help. Are you trying to design a new custom backpropagation method or loss function, or are you still using the standard cross-entropy loss?

Comment: @PeaBrane It uses a2c. let's say that I get output of [0.9, 0.1] from my neural network. I run backward propagation and set desired output to [0.91, 0.09]. Ideally if I were to rerun the program with the same input after backwards propagation and get [0.905, 0.095] the propagate backward clearly seems to be working. lets say instead I get [0.895, 0.105] instead. Does this mean that my neural network is not working? In my case, I would have original output: [0.34, 0.28, 0.38, -0.07], desired output: [0.36, 0.27, 0.37, 0.98], and end up getting [0.33, 0.275, 0.375, -0.02]. 75% ofThemMvInRtDirec

Comment: of them move in the right direction. Do you see my problem now. It is not really gradient descent but more of the function of a neural network. A neural network that is probably not implemented properly. bc i implemented it.